# Passing a component to apolloprovider with typescript

Tags: typescript, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to pass in a react component to ApolloProvider to use. I am using typescript so types etc. need to be declared correctly.

My idea was to do the following

```
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo'; 

class ProjectRequest{

    public provideApolloToComponent(PassedComponent: Component) {
        const client = new ApolloClient({
            link: new HttpLink(),
            cache: new InMemoryCache(),
          });
        return (<ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <PassedComponent />
        </ApolloProvider>);
    }
```

However I get the following Errors:

For ApolloProvider

```
Generic type 'ApolloProvider<TCache>' requires 1 type argument(s)
```

For PassedComponent

```
  Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)
'PassedComponent' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.
```

and for the end ApolloProvider jsx element

```
Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)
Unterminated regular expression literal.
```

which I assume will be fixed when the PassedComponent is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just putting this in here in case anyone ends up in a similar situation. I'm on a project that I'm not particularly familiar with yet, and they have set up their typescript in I suppose a normal way but one which I generally don't use so the .ts extension is pure typescript. 
So the file I was editing was a pure ts file, and not a tsx. which meant all my React code was throwing weird errors like you saw, once I fixed that I saw that there were other errors.

The actual code of provideApolloToComponent at the end looked like the following

```
public provideApolloToComponent(PassedComponent: React.ReactType) {
        let localclient = new ApolloClient({
            link: new HttpLink(),
            cache: new InMemoryCache(),
        });
        return (<ApolloProvider client={localclient}>
                   <PassedComponent />
                </ApolloProvider>
        );
    }
```